# Can't change the xdg-open url-handler to Firefox

Tags: manjaro, i3, xdg-open

My problem is that many programs call xdg-open to open websites but on my Manjaro system (based on Arch Linux) this is somehow bound to cups :)

When such a call to xdg-open happens, the CPU usage goes up a lot, without anything happens. I restart because the laptop gets hot very quickly.

```
~ $ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
cups.desktop
```

When I want to change that, I get the following response:

```
~ $ xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
xdg-settings: $BROWSER is set and can't be changed with xdg-settings
```

I can go ahead and change the environment variable for the browser and I'm fixed, BUT only for this one terminal. How could I make this change permanent or add it to autostart?

I'm using: i3 4.12, fish shell

Comment: I don't use a desktop, so don't have the right setup and cannot say what GUI tool does this for you, but there is a file `~/.local/share/applications/preferred-web-browser.desktop` on my system that has `Exec=firefox %u` in it.

Comment: thanks meuh. my issues arise from programs calling xdg-open though which then calls the connected '.desktop' file, that is connected with the task (=default-web-browser in this case). The .desktop file that gets called is cups.desktop, which i find a bit weird and i'm considering deleting cups, because i don't print anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the BROWSER variable in `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment` and eventually in your `~/.bashrc`. It is probably set to `/usr/bin/xdg-open` so you should consider to change it to avoid the recursive call.

Comment: I have no browser variable in any of those files, is this no longer viable for recent vers?

Comment: My experience: I had `BROWSER=firefox` in `~/.bashrc` but an application still opened URLs in chromium. `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` produced `chromium.desktop`, but wouldn't let me set it due to `$BROWSER` existing. I had to open a new terminal, do `export BROWSER=""`, then run `xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop` and then the application opened urls in firefox. I find that weird, as it's acting like `$BROWSER` supersedes (and thus won't set), but it wasn't occuring like this in practice. Adding note for anyone else running into this.

Answer (score 16):

I had this issue since Chromium made itself the default browser each time I installed it.

Using [`xdg-mime`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-mime) fixed it:

```
xdg-mime default firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/https x-scheme-handler/http
```

On my Arch Linux system, this added two lines to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, associating HTTP and HTTPS with Firefox.

Now I can have both Firefox and Chromium installed with Firefox being the default browser.

Comment: Add `text/html` as an argument to also handle .html files in the file system.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me in Crostini to keep using garcon to open the native browser in ChromeOS but use the chrome binary for running selenium

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `xdg-settings` doesn't like that `BROWSER` variable is set in the current shell. Removing it will make it happy:

```
~ $ unset BROWSER
~ $ xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
```

The first command above will change the variable only for this one terminal, but the second one (which is the objective) will take effect across terminals.

On my machine, it looked like this:

```
~ $ grep -sch BROWSER /etc/* ~/.*rc | uniq
0

~ $ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
cups.desktop

~ $ xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop

xdg-settings: $BROWSER is set and can't be changed with xdg-settings

~ $ (
  unset BROWSER
  xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
)

~ $ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
firefox.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was editing the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.
This is what you do under the hood with the xdg-mime command mentioned earlier. The good thing is that you can easily look which are your defaults and for which files. Some more details:

- The dir `~/.local/share/applications` contains .desktop files for each user application that you can "link" to xdg-open.
- As I mentioned, to set one of these applications as default for any desired file type, edit the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
- Tip: Although deprecated, several applications still read/write to `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. To simplify maintenance, simply symlink it to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
- [More info and reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_MIME_Applications#:%7E:text=mimeapps.list.-,mimeapps.list,-The%20XDG%20standard)