# Google Chrome Stable Set as Default in Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: browser

I have Lubuntu 18.10 and can't seem to make Google Chrome Stable the default browser. I read online to go here in the terminal and choose browser and press enter, BUT, this does not work:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

I set up my keyboard with shortcut keys to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to pop up my browser, but Firefox pops up instead. How can I make Google Chrome my default browser in Lubuntu 18.10?

Comment: Hello Karen. You appear to be using two different accounts with the same name. I would recommend that you [merge them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), which will make editing your own question much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and do:

```
export BROWSER=""
xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop
```

In the last step, you can use google-chrome-stable.desktop instead of google-chrome.desktop.

Credit is due to the comment of the accepted answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310892

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on: Ubuntu 22.10 ("Kinetic")

- Preferences > LXQt Settings > File Associations > Default Applications tab > Web Browser (presently set to Google Chrome)
- choose change > Firefox  > ok
- choose change > choose Google Chrome > ok
- close.

Answer (score -1):

I just uninstalled firefox and google chrome is now the default browser.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! This looks like a workaround (e.g. what about users that may want to keep both the browsers installed?). Any idea on how to achieve the same result using system settings?